# Login ht password login on page returns error 401

Tags: mysql, apache, authentication, apache2

I'm having an issue with on of my users.
She is using MacOSX 10.9.
In the logs I only can see the Error 401 but nothing else.

Here's the apache2 config entry:

```
Alias /path/toscript /home/path/user/xxxxx/script
<Location /path/toscript >
    AuthName "DEVInfo"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /dev/null
    require valid-user
    AuthMYSQL on
    AuthBasicAuthoritative off
    AuthMySQL_Authoritative on
    AuthMySQL_Host host
    AuthMySQL_User auth
    AuthMySQL_Password VERY_SECURED_PASSWORD
    AuthMySQL_DB auth
    AuthMySQL_Password_Table user
    AuthMySQL_Username_Field name
    AuthMySQL_Password_Field passwd
    AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords off
    AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types Crypt_DES PHP_MD5
</Location>
```

She can login on one of the pages.
But the rest doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Well I guess the easiest way would be to look for an alternative way of login authentification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could find it out, that multiple http auths are colliding and that's the reason Only certain pages work.